# comparing a character with a set of characters c++

Tags: c++

is there a way to compare a single character with a set of characters?

eg:

```
char a;
if(a in {'q','w','e','r','t','y','u'})
      return true;
else return false;
```

i need something like this.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
std::string chars = "qwertyu";
char c = 'w';
if (chars.find(c) != std::string::npos) {
  // It's there
}
```

Or you could use a set - if you need to lookup often that's faster.

```
std::set<char> chars;
char const * CharList = "qwertyu";
chars.insert(CharList, CharList + strlen(CharList));
if (chars.find('q') != chars.end())  {
  // It's there
}
```

EDIT: As Steve Jessop's suggested: You can also use `chars.count('q')` instead of `find('q') != end()`

You could also use a bitmap of present chars (e.g. `vector<bool>`) but that's overly complex unless you do this a few million times a second.

Comment: @Erik: I suggest you steal at least some of my code for using the set. `count` is good :-)

Comment: @Steve Jessop: Didn't think of `count`, never use it hehe. I find explicit comparison to end more readable though.

Comment: @Erik: fair enough. I think of the `count` function for `set` and `map` as secretly being called `contains`, so readability here is just about familiarity. For `multi_set` and `multi_map` of course it's potentially inefficient.

Comment: @Steve: how do you know that it is not inefficient for set?  Are you sure that since it can only be 0 or 1, it will stop at the first occurrence?

Comment: @stefaanv: Theoretically, it doesn't matter. Even if it checked the next element, it would be O(log N)+O(1), which is still O(log N). Practically, the library implementors are quite competent.

Comment: @stefaanv: well, you never *know* that something is efficient in absolute terms, that's a quality-of-implementation issue. But there's no reason for `set::count` to be inefficient for this, and it's not allowed to scan the whole set. In a multiset, potentially there are a lot of matches, so at absolute theoretical best it does an upper and a lower search and then figures out the number of nodes in between using records stored in the nodes. But it's allowed to be linear in the number of matches, so at worst it is, which clearly is inefficient if you only care whether there's 0 vs more than 0.

Comment: @Steve and @MSalters: thanks, I was just asking because that always stopped me from using count(), because find() is guaranteed to be O(log N).

Answer (score 11):

Use strchr:

```
return strchr("qwertyu", a);
```

There's no need to write, "if x return true else return false," just, "return x".

Comment: Should note that strchr is in the <cstring>/<string.h> header.

Answer (score 0):

```
const char[] letters = {...};
char a = ...;
bool found = false;
for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(letters); i++) {
    if (letters[i] == a)
        found = true;
}
if (found) {
    ...
} else {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
std::string s="qwertyu";
return s.find(a) != std::string::npos;
```